# Composer Laravel Install Error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel with composer. I'm getting this error when i run create-project command.

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist appName`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

# Same error with many other versions (see gist)

Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
```

I also tried to install by cloning Laravel repository and running composer install command and still got the same error.

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/waleedahmad/a3eaf0aa5a3b279fc6c37b54f854d87c) for complete error message. Am i doing something wrong? I tried clearing composer cache and everything. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It was bug on composer tagging. Try now, it should work.